# Less @import issue

Tags: css, git, less

I am trying to compile LESS files together.

```
/* frameworks */
@gitpath: "./../../../../git/";

@import "@{gitpath}normalize.css/normalize.css";
@import "@{gitpath}lesshat/build/lesshat-prefixed.less";
@import "@{gitpath}Semantic-UI/build/packaged/css/semantic.css";

/*custom*/
@import "variables.less";
@import "layout.less";
```

The problem is imports of normalize.css and semantic.css don't get compiled.

I tried to use inline directive:

```
@import (inline) "@{gitpath}normalize.css/normalize.css";
```

but then minification flag [-x] does not work when compiling through lessc command.

Any idea how to deal with this? Or better, is there any better practice how to use up-to-date CSS libraries in your projects? Currently I am storing them in a local git repository and try to use them among my projects.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, but that was a typo. It is not the cause.

Comment: What do the normalize.css and semantic.css files have in them? Are they pure CSS? Inline would import the source file but would not process it.

Comment: Just don't use `-x`. It may sound strange but there's no reason to use this option these days (if you need minified CSS use "normal" minifier with `--clean-css` option). The `-x` option applies only to compiled CSS and since `(inline)` css imports are output `as is` w/o any compilation they are not affected by this option.

Comment: Thank you guys, for now I used (inline) directives for the CSS file imports and I minify the result of compilation using --clean-css flag. I can continue with my work and later I will search for better workflow practices.